# Autofill Example with Redux-Form

Tags: redux-form

Does anyone have a simple autofill example using redux-form v6? I would use defaultValue, but I guess redux-form renders controlled inputs. I also would like to avoid setStates if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use initialValues property.
Example:

```
<FormPost
  enableReinitialize
  initialValues={
    name: 'Default Name'   
  }
/>
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem.

Comment: @jaysig could you up comment :)